# Help! I just got Ubuntu 16.04 but nothing is really working

Tags: sound

I recentely bought a new computer from Dell (i15 5567 D408) and it came with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and I've already have a lot of headache, like when I first started I tried to use headphones and the computer got completely soundless, I searched a lot of about it and I've tried some things, but nothing worked, so I've decided to upload some things that Ubuntu was requesting, but then it loses all my sound drivers (the only that was left was:"dummy output"), without saying that my Ubuntu Sofwtare wasn't working at all (tried a lot of things and nothing worked). So I've decided to reinstall everything again (with a boot cd), and when a restarted, everything was still the same!
But then I searched something to help me work out the Ubuntu Software, and I found it this command:

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade gnome-software

and it works! And I intalled the only sound driver back from Ubuntu Software (that is working). But now there is no sound again!! And everything looks fine, I don't know what is happening, and it have this locking problems and the only way to solve this is to turn off the computer and start again, I've already restarted this computer like 8 times just today!! Please help me, is that how Ubuntu works? 
Thank you already.

(I apologize if my english isn't good, it's not my native language.)

Answer (score 1):

With a new Dell computer you get 1 year of free support. That includes everything including replacing motherboards and other defective parts. Dell also has excellent support forums.

I'm not familiar with your particular Dell product but mine hasn't had any major problems. There have been some minor ones which I was able to solve by googling my problem.

Although there are many talented people here to help with your problems my suggestion would be to contact Dell first because your new computer purchase includes there free support. Keep in mind they probably know your computer and it's specific problems with pre-installed Ubuntu better than most of us here.